# Protractor on AWS Lambda via NodeJS

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium, protractor, aws-lambda, google-chrome-headless

I have a NodeJS function on AWS Lambda that is able to use `selenium-webdriver` node module and run chrome with `--headless` tags.

However, I want to convert this to use protractor and run specs.

Is there a way to run protractor via NodeJS to use headless chrome?